# Groovy, Lego EV3

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

to  Willow Garage/ ROS

I would like to know if Groovy will support lego NXT and I hope in the future Lego EV3, also is supported, as those are a very good initial environment to learn ROS

as such they are not only very flexible  platform to learn but very versatile and and excellent prototyping platform

could you please share with me your views, and thoughts about this

Many Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52224/groovy,-lego-ev3/) by [Harry](https://answers.ros.org/users/3616/harry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

same here http://answers.ros.org/question/52836/lego-nxt-ros-working-on-groovy-galapagos/?comment=69874#comment-69874 never heard of ev3

---

Originally posted by [msieber](https://answers.ros.org/users/3823/msieber/) with karma: 181 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0